# Hide tab content on click outside of the tab and tab content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is elementor tab example. When I click on tab content section appears. I want to close content section on click on any other part of page. But not in tab and tab content. Also not effect on tabs functionality. If I click on tab again it shows its content again.

One class adds on click in tabs "tab-current" that changes the background color of the tab. The active content appears and class is "content-current".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    if (!jQuery(event.target).closest('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').length) {
      jQuery('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').removeClass('tab-current');
    }
    if (!jQuery(event.target).closest('.premium-tabs-content-section').length) {
      jQuery('.premium-tabs-content-section').removeClass('content-current');
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 1</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 2</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "Edit this snippet" and provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://codepen.io/Vikaspatel/pen/abvgBQa

you can check here. but classes are different here.

Comment: We don't want a random example on an external platform that uses different code. Put what you _actually_ got, into the question, in form of a proper [mre].

Comment: Your classes in the pen don't match the classes in the question, but otherwise it more or less works - just need to combine *both* .closest checks and then both removeClasses rather than treating them separately.  https://jsfiddle.net/rcqe7yad/  ProTip: Use an IDE that highlights mistakes in the HTML (even jsfiddle does this)

Answer (score 2):

it would be cool if you could also add some CSS to have a complete preview. For now, I have a suggestion. I **added my simple CSS** to illustrate it.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
      var tabContainer = jQuery('.tabs');
      var contentContainer = jQuery('.content');

      // Check if the click is outside tabs and content
      if (
        !jQuery(event.target).closest('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').length &&
        !jQuery(event.target).closest('.premium-tabs-content-section').length
      ) {
        // Remove active class from tabs and content
        tabContainer.find('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').removeClass('tab-current');
        contentContainer.find('.premium-tabs-content-section').removeClass('content-current');
      }

    });

    // Add click event to tabs
    jQuery('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').click(function() {
      // Remove active class from all tabs
      jQuery('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').removeClass('tab-current');
      // Add active class to the clicked tab
      jQuery(this).addClass('tab-current');

      // Remove active class from all content sections
      jQuery('.premium-tabs-content-section').removeClass('content-current');
      // Add active class to the corresponding content section
      var index = jQuery(this).index();
      jQuery('.premium-tabs-content-section').eq(index).addClass('content-current');
    });
  });
```

```css
    .tabs {
      display: flex;
    }

    .premium-tabs-nav-list-item {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .content {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .premium-tabs-content-section {
      display: none;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .content-current {
      display: block;
    }

    .tab-current {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Elementor Tab Example</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="tabs">
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-nav-list-item">Tab 3</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 1</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 2</div>
  <div class="premium-tabs-content-section">Content 3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cache the elements: `const $listItems = $('.premium-tabs-nav-list-item').on('click',function() { $listItems.removeClass('tab-current');`

Comment: Not hiding the content section on click other part of page.

can you please check this example: https://codepen.io/Nasir-Kamal/pen/ExMQGxm

if you remove my js code its by default behavior of tabs. but I want when user click on free space of the page active tab and active section in default layout. and if user click again on tab it actives is section

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "*Not hiding the content section on click other part of page*" - this code does *exactly* what you've asked for: "*Hide tab content on click outside of the tab and tab content*" and "*I want to close content section on click on any other part of page*" - there's no mention of restoring to "default layout" which would be the opposite of "hide/close content".   Please ensure your question **asks what you actually want**.

Comment: @NasirKamal

Take the code I provided as an example based on your question. So, you want Tab 1 to be active by default. Later, if the user clicks on Tab 2, it becomes active, but if they click on a free space, it returns to the active Tab 1? Am I understanding it correctly?